Correlation taken for positive and negative values vs the absolute value of those values.
I have a data set that basically comes down to this. Say thirty people start from x=0 and the first one takes one step in the positive direction, the second takes two steps in the negative direction, the third takes three steps in the positive direction, etc. But each person has different length steps. In Excel, I have set it up where
Column A contains 1 through 30,
Column B is  =A1+A1*NORM.INV(RAND(),0,0.6)
Column C is =IF(ISEVEN(A1),-A1,A1)
Column D is =IF(ISEVEN(A1),-B1,B1)
The correlation between columns A and B is about 60% and columns C and D is about 90%. I am assuming that, everything else being equal, the 60% better represents the data, but looking at the correlation formula, I can’t figure out a general rule for the difference between these two correlation values. I’d like to know so I can present the data correctly.
The average of Columns A and B is about 15 or -15, depending on which way you step, and the average of Columns C and D is about zero, so the distance between where the person ends up and each of these averages is going to be about double for Columns A and B, but putting that into the correlation formula, everything nulls out and I get a value of one, that is, the correlations should be equal, which cannot be the case. I’m assuming this problem has come up before, but when I google it, I get people talking about one and two-tailed tests.
